# $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-{0}) \cong \tilde{H_{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^n-{0})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was going through my class notes and came to this line: $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-{0}) \cong \widetilde{H_{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^n-{0})$, where $\tilde{H_n}$ is the reduced homology. I am trying to figure out if it is correct and, if so, how to prove it, but I am stuck. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the long exact sequence of the pair $(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^n - 0)$ (in reduced homology): $$\dots \to H_n(\Bbb R^n) \to H_n(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^n - 0) \to \tilde{H}_{n-1}(\Bbb R^n - 0) \to \tilde H_{n-1}(\Bbb R^n) \to \dots$$
Because $\Bbb R^n$ is contractible, the outer two terms vanish, so the middle map must be an isomorphism.